# Find rows with incomplete set depending on a factor, then replace values that exist by NA for the incomplete set

Tags: r, tidyr, plyr

I cannot work this one out.

I have an incomplete dataset (many rows and variables) with one factor that specify whether all the other variables are pre- or post- something. I need to get summary statistics for all variables pre- and post- only including rows where the pre- AND post- values are not NA.

I am trying to find a way to replace existing values with NA if the set is incomplete separately for each variable.

The following is a simple example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
  df = data.frame(
    id = c(1,1,2,2),
    myfactor = as.factor(c(1,2,1,2)),
    var2change = c(10,10,NA,20),
    var3change = c(5,10,15,20),
    var4change = c(NA,2,3,8)
     )
```

which leads to:

```
  id myfactor var2change var3change var4change
1  1        1         10          5         NA
2  1        2         10         10          2
3  2        1         NA         15          3
4  2        2         20         20          8
```

My desired output would be:

```
  id myfactor var2change var3change var4change
1  1        1         10          5         NA
2  1        2         10         10         NA
3  2        1         NA         15          3
4  2        2         NA         20          8
```

I have much more than one variable to deal with and the set is incomplete in a different way for each variable independently. I have the feeling this may be achieved with smart use of existing functions from the plyr / tidyr packages but I cannot find an elegant way to apply the concepts to my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question clearly. Can you increase the number of columns to 4-5 and show example and expected output for it. Also explain the logic of changing values to `NA`.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question. The logic is that I have paired data for two time points (or two myfactor above) and I want the summary statistics to only include data that I have for both time points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `id` and if any value has `NA` in it replace all of them with `NA`. To apply a function to multiple columns we use `across`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('var'), ~if(any(is.na(.))) NA else .))
  #for dplyr < 1.0.0 we can use `mutate_at`
  #mutate_at(vars(starts_with('var')), ~if(any(is.na(.))) NA else .)

#     id myfactor var2change var3change var4change
#  <dbl> <fct>         <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1     1 1                10          5         NA
#2     1 2                10         10         NA
#3     2 1                NA         15          3
#4     2 2                NA         20          8
```

Comment: Great! Now I need to find a way to get all the variables I want using starts_with and other functions (my variable names aren't as systematic as var...).

Comment: you can use range of columns `var2change:var4change` or by position `3:5` in it.

Comment: yep, thanks a lot! Just for info, I had to then ungroup() because I needed to get rid of the group_by variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the dataset you have is ordered, so each pair of observations is grouped by their row index.

By default, the `mean()` function will return an `NA` if any of the inputs to it are `NA`. This is therefore a neat way of getting an `NA` by group, using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(
  myfactor = as.factor(c(1,2,1,2)),
  var2change = c(10,10,NA,20)
)

# 1 Create ID variable to group rows in pairs
id = c()
j = 0
for (i in 1:length(df$var2change)){
  k = floor(j/2)
  id = c(id, k)
  j = j + 1
}
df$id = id

# Set all variables within group to NA if one of them is
df = df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(var_changed = mean(var2change))
```

If you have an explicit ID variable in your data, you can replace the first part of this solution.

EDIT: doing this for multiple variables (based on change to the question):

```
df = data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,2,2),
  myfactor = as.factor(c(1,2,1,2)),
  var2change = c(10,10,NA,20),
  var3change = c(5,10,15,20),
  var4change = c(NA,2,3,8)
)
for (col in 2:4) {
  col = paste0("var", col, "change")
  df = df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(new_col = mean(get(col))) 
  df[["new_col"]] = ifelse(is.na(df["new_col"]), NA, df[[col]])
  df[col] = NULL
  names(df)[names(df) == "new_col"] <- col
}
```

If speed is an issue, you could speed this up by moving the `group_by` outside the loop

Comment: Thanks, this is clever. However, I  have many other variables and I'd like to avoid using repeated call to mutate.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have a grouping variable (`group`) as well as your time variable (`myfactor`). Then you can do some finangling to create the variables you want with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(
  group = rep(c(1,2), each = 2),
  myfactor = as.factor(c(1,2,1,2)),
  var2change = c(10,10,NA,20)
)

df %>% group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(var3change = all(!is.na(var2change)),
         var4change = if_else(var3change, var2change, as.numeric(NA)))
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I do have a grouping variable. But, I'd like to avoid multiple call to mutate since I have many variables.